# how to add Custom Data to each State Objects Dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

In the below example i have custom data like `data:{roles:[]}` like this i need to add custom data properties dynamically like `data:{user:[]}` for each state

```
 .state('WorkArea', {
   parent: 'site',
   url: '/WorkArea',
   data: {
       roles: ['User', 'Dev']
   },
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Define it in this way:

 .state('WorkArea', {
   parent: 'site',
   url: '/WorkArea',
   data: {
       roles: (function() {
                return ['User', 'Dev'];
              })()
   },
 })
```

You can use IIFE for this case to dynamically add properties to data attribute.

In your app.run use:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
    var roles = toState.data.roles ;
    console.log(roles);
   // your custom logic here for that state
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
You can attach custom data to the state object (we recommend using a data property to avoid conflicts).

```
// Example shows an object-based state and a string-based state
var contacts = { 
name: 'contacts',
templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
data: {
    customData1: 5,
    customData2: "blue"
}  
}
$stateProvider
  .state(contacts)
  .state('contacts.list', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
  data: {
    customData1: 44,
    customData2: "red"
} 
  })
```

With the above example states you could access the data like this:

```
function Ctrl($state){
console.log($state.current.data.customData1) // outputs 5;
console.log($state.current.data.customData2) // outputs "blue";
}
```